# Trouble installing package fora Julia in Windows behind firewall (although I can install packages with R in the same conditions)

Tags: package, installation, julia, firewall

I'm normally using Julia (1.3) on my MacOS and don't have any trouble installing package. I also want to use Julia (1.3) at work where I have Windows 10 and a firewall and where I have no trouble installing new packages for R. However when I try to install packages for Julia, the following error message Comes.

How could I fix the problem?

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
   Cloning default registries into `C:\Users\******\.julia`
   Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:OS, failed to send request: The operation timed out
)
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:113
 [2] #clone#4(::String, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,LibGit2.CachedCredentials,Tuple{Symbol},NamedTuple{(:credentials,),Tuple{LibGit2.CachedCredentials}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.GitTools.clone), ::String, ::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\GitTools.jl:131
 [3] #clone at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [4] (::Pkg.Types.var"#124#126"{Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec,String})(::LibGit2.CachedCredentials) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:1029
 [5] shred!(::Pkg.Types.var"#124#126"{Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec,String}, ::LibGit2.CachedCredentials) at .\secretbuffer.jl:184
 [6] clone_or_cp_registries(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec,1}, ::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:1028
 [7] clone_or_cp_registries at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:1013 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [8] clone_default_registries() at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:963
 [9] find_registered!(::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:1244
 [10] registry_resolve!(::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:880
 [11] #add#25(::Bool, ::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Windows, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.add), ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:95
 [12] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:72
 [13] #add#24 at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:69 [inlined]
 [14] add at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:69 [inlined]
 [15] #add#21 at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [16] add at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [17] #add#20(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.add), ::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:66
 [18] add(::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:66
 [19] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1
caused by [exception 1]
GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:OS, failed to send request: The operation timed out
)
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\LibGit2\src\error.jl:101 [inlined]
 [2] clone(::String, ::String, ::LibGit2.CloneOptions) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\LibGit2\src\repository.jl:459
 [3] #clone#131(::String, ::Bool, ::Ptr{Nothing}, ::LibGit2.CachedCredentials, ::Dict{Symbol,Tuple{Ptr{Nothing},Any}}, ::typeof(LibGit2.clone), ::String, ::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\LibGit2\src\LibGit2.jl:580
 [4] #clone at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [5] #clone#4(::String, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,LibGit2.CachedCredentials,Tuple{Symbol},NamedTuple{(:credentials,),Tuple{LibGit2.CachedCredentials}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.GitTools.clone), ::String, ::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\GitTools.jl:123
 [6] #clone at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [7] (::Pkg.Types.var"#124#126"{Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec,String})(::LibGit2.CachedCredentials) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:1029
 [8] shred!(::Pkg.Types.var"#124#126"{Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec,String}, ::LibGit2.CachedCredentials) at .\secretbuffer.jl:184
 [9] clone_or_cp_registries(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec,1}, ::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:1028
 [10] clone_or_cp_registries at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:1013 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [11] clone_default_registries() at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:963
 [12] find_registered!(::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:1244
 [13] registry_resolve!(::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:880
 [14] #add#25(::Bool, ::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Windows, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.add), ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:95
 [15] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:72
 [16] #add#24 at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:69 [inlined]
 [17] add at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:69 [inlined]
 [18] #add#21 at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [19] add at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [20] #add#20(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.add), ::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:66
 [21] add(::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\API.jl:66
 [22] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a quick fix, try this, firstly, install git so you can get access to git bash

Navigate to `C:\Users\******\.julia\registries\General` open up git bash and do a git pull.

If you have set up the git config properly then you should be able to pull the package registry.

Now try to `Pkg.add("....")` again. If that fails, go to

`C:\Users\******\.julia\dev` and in git bash `git pull https://github.com/urlto/PkgYouWantToInstall.jl` and then rename the folder to get rid of the `.jl` suffix.

Go to Julia repo, and do `]dev PkgYouWantToInstall`.

Comment:
The Behind Corporate Proxy Issue (BCPI) is bigger than the Time-to-first-plot (TTFP) issue but is less visible so doesn't receive as much attention. But it's the biggest drag to Julia adoption. Even bigger than TTFP, IMHO.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answer @xiaodai. I'll try to implement it as soon as I get back to my computer at work in a few days. For the more broader picture I'm a non-professional coder and currently don't use with github. The few people I code with don't either. I'm also not planning to upload my code on Github. The only advantage I see by using git would be to track changes. I my situation, do you think that, there is no other way to solve the problem? Last (broadest) point: is there some plan in the Julia community to get over BCPI if this is the biggest drag to Julia adoption

Comment: The problem is libgit2 I think. We just merged https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/pull/1444 however, so that should help a lot.

Comment: ecjb: the solution of xiaodai doesn't assume you want to open a GitHub account or host your projects in GitHub, it is simply that most packages are actually hosted on GitHub, and so if you need that packages you need to download ("clone") that packages from GitHub. The default git client embedded in Julia has problems under corporate firewall, hence the @ecjb workaround to use the standard git client to "download" the packages and make them available to Julia.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you for your insigntful answers. I will try to implement it as soon as possible